# Are the subjunctives of "brauchen" and "verbrauchen" different?

Tags: verb

There seems to be a difference when building subjunctives from the verb *"brauchen"* when used alone, or in the composite verb *"verbrauchen"*.

> Hätten wir überall Energiesparlampen, **verbrauchten** wir nur halb so viel Strom.
>   Hätten wir mehr Geld, **bräuchten** wir keine Schulden zu machen.

Building the subjunctives the other way round then

> *Hätten wir überall Energiesparlampen, **verbräuchten** wir nur halb so viel Strom.*

sounds disastrously wrong. But the second case

> *Hätten wir mehr Geld, **brauchten** wir keine Schulden zu machen.*

sounds correct too.

Therefore I do have a considerable uncertainty on how to build the subjunctives here. [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/brauchen) and [Canoonet](http://canoonet.eu/services/Controller?dispatch=inflection&input=brauchen&features=%28Cat%20V%29%28Aux%20haben%29&country=D&lookup=caseInSensitive) say that *"brauchte"* is the correct form. However I hardly hear a subjunctive other than *"bräuchte"*.

Is there any peculiar reason why we treat *"brauchen"* differently? Or am I only fooled by a regional dialect influence that interferes with my intuition here?

Comment: [This ngram seems to be relevant.](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=br%C3%A4uchte&year_start=1880&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=1)

Comment: [This google search is also helpful.](http://www.google.de/#q="brauchte"+"bräuchte")

Comment: @Hendrik: I think an ngram of a single word without a comparison is next to useless.

Comment: @musiKk: In this particular case I don't think so. We are talking about an increase by a _factor of about 100_ here. In the 19th century, "bräuchte" was hardly ever used.

Comment: Speaking of ngrams, I think they even don't prove anything while comparing two terms.

Comment: @Hendrik: And what would be your conclusion if all synonyms also increased by the same factor? Hopefully a different one than in the case where synonyms did not increase or even decreased.

Comment: @musiKk: I don't know of any synonym of "brauchen". But I do agree that it's a good idea to just make sure and check if the usage of "brauchen" has changed over the decades - [it has fluctuated only a bit](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=brauchen&year_start=1880&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ansgar](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/3708/161) is right, but maybe not for long anymore ;)

Many (if not most) subjunctives are composed the same way as the past tense. Which brings up the problem of differentiation:

> Ich brauchte das Geld.

What does that sentence mean? Maybe

> Ich brauchte das Geld gestern.

oder

> Ich brauchte das Geld noch heute. <sup><sub>(Yes, you can use "Ich brauche" here also, but that's not the point)</sub></sup>

To avoid this problem you can use the construction with "würden", but it is nice to have a word which already tells the difference precisely. And because in German we often do that with äöu-constructions (like "helfen" -> "hülfen" or "hälfen"), doing it with "brauchen" also suggests itself.

The language is living, so "bräuchte" could be on its way to Standard German. You are one of the people who decides that. If it is used more often it could replace "brauchte" as subjunctive (or be an official alternative). And then we would have a distinction between subjunctive and past tense, which is necessary if you ask me.

Answer (score 4):

The correct subjunctive is *brauchten*, but in colloquial usage, one very often finds *bräuchten*.

Comment: A reference would be cool ;)

Comment: http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/brauchen_(Konjugation)

Comment: There isn't any complete reference for *verbrauchen*, just this http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/verbrauchen

Comment: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/brauchen, older printed editions do not mention _bräuchte_ at all.

Comment: In colloquial usage you might even put the first sentence as `Hätten wir überall Energiesparlampen, würden wir nur halb so viel Strom brauchen.`